# React - Button is not disabled during the ajax call, toast is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have few buttons on the page and if I click the button ajax call is made. I want to disable the button so the user doesnt click it again and another ajax call is not made.

I tried the below code but the button is not disabling.
I want to show the notification on success in react as well - I tried toast but its not working too.

Is there any other way I can show a balloon popup in react ?

Please suggest,

```
    onClickRun(params) {

    const url = `/api/${params}/run`;
    const id = "run"+params;
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend :() =>{
           // $("#run"+params).classList.add("cursorDisabled");
           // $("#run"+params).attr('disabled',true);   
            document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById(id).classList.add('cursorDisabled');             
        },
        success: (response) => { 
            if(!response.error) {

                // toast({
                //     message: 'Pipeline ran successfully.',
                //     flavor: 'success',
                //     options: { timeOut: 5000 }
                // });
                //$("#"+params).classList.remove("cursorDisabled");
                //$("#run"+params).attr('disabled',false);
                document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
                  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('cursorDisabled'); 
                location.reload(true);
            }
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

CSS code :

```
.cursorDisabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    color: gray;
}
```

Button :

```
<button id= {"run"+col.name} type="button" onClick={() =>  this.onClickRun(col.name)} <i className="icon-play-filled"></i>
                                </button>
```

Comment: Why does signature method has 3 params (2 unused) and you just call with `this.onClickRun(col.name)` ?

Comment: removed it. its just i was using it before n then removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm so there's an easy fix, using react's setState method.
You need to the following changes

1. `<button id= {"run"+col.name} type="button" onClick={() =>  this.onClickRun(col.name)} <i className="icon-play-filled"></i>`
   replace this with

`<button id= {"run"+col.name} className={this.state.clickedButton === col.name ? 'cursorDisabled' : ''} disabled={this.state.clickedButton === col.name} type="button" onClick={() =>  this.onClickRun(col.name)} <i className="icon-play-filled"></i>`;

  2.

```
onClickRun(params) {

    const url = `/api/${params}/run`;
    const id = "run"+params;
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend :() =>{
           // $("#run"+params).classList.add("cursorDisabled");
           // $("#run"+params).attr('disabled',true);   
            document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById(id).classList.add('cursorDisabled');
            this.setState({
              clickedButton: params
            })             
        },
        success: (response) => {
            this.setState({
              clickedButton: ''
            })
            if(!response.error) {

                // toast({
                //     message: 'Pipeline ran successfully.',
                //     flavor: 'success',
                //     options: { timeOut: 5000 }
                // });
                //$("#"+params).classList.remove("cursorDisabled");
                //$("#run"+params).attr('disabled',false);
                document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
                  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('cursorDisabled'); 
                location.reload(true);
            }
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log("error");
            this.setState({
              clickedButton: ''
            })
        }
    });
}
```

3. Add a new state using

```
state = {
  clickedButton: ''
}
```

You are all set.

Comment: Here's an working copy.
https://codesandbox.io/s/0xr5kj3r60?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

Use only react state in your case.
Here the example

```
const ajax = ({beforeSend, success}) => {
  beforeSend();
  setTimeout(success, 2000);
}

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: ''
  }
  handleClick = (params) => {
    ajax({
      beforeSend: () => {
        this.setState({isLoading: params})
      },
      success: () => {
        this.setState({isLoading: ''});
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {isLoading} = this.state;
    return <div>
      <button disabled={isLoading === 'b1'} onClick={() => this.handleClick('b1')}>{isLoading === 'b1' ? '...loading' : 'b1'}</button>    
    <button disabled={isLoading === 'b2'} onClick={() => this.handleClick('b2')}>{isLoading === 'b2' ? '...loading' : 'b2'}</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/kruglay/pen/BbodJZ?editors=0010)

but the better architecture decision is create separate component for each button and set isLoading as boolean

Answer (score 0):

html buttons have a disabled attribute. I see you trying to set it, but I recommend using that attribute on the button declaration and on the attribute use a react expression to check a variable in your component's state. Set and remove the state in your handler.

If you are using a recent version of react, this can be done very easily with hooks. Otherwise, call this.setState

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use Modal and redux-saga for side effects.

1) When you click on button, fire an action which redux-saga will catch

2) redux-saga will show Modal with loading icon and make ajax call and wait till ajax call returns.

3) After call returns, hide Modal.

4) Modal should be non clickable. So that user is not able to click anywhere when your ajax call is in progress